# Iterate over a 2d numpy array until it contains only some specific values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array which contains float numbers in each cell.

I'd like to iterate over it and change value of each cell (if a specific condition is matched), until it contains only the values **1**, **-1**, or **NaN** in each cell.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So NaN is in your original array? Doesn't indexing work? like `myarray[myarray>1]=1` and the same for the other side

Comment: no my original array have float values, I do indexing with two simple nested for per each row and each column, and it works. My problem is define the ending condition (stop when all cells contains 1 or -1 or NaN)

Comment: So I assume the operation (that you haven't mentioned here) has to be in every loop even though iterating over all the elements is super slow and it generates NaNs, then you can just use `while np.any((myarray>1)+(myarray<-1)+~np.isnan(myarray))`

Answer (score 1):

In numpy you can use a conditional indexing. i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)
c =  x > 5 
print c
```

will give

```
array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  
True], dtype=bool)
```

and finally use the condition

```
x[c] = -1
print x
```

gives `array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5, -1, -1, -1, -1])`